# eclipse sorting bookmarks by creation time

Tags: eclipse, sorting, bookmarks

My eclipse workspace has about 70 interdependent java projects and bookmarks set in various areas of interest over the last few months.

I like to see the bookmarks sorted by creation time so that I can see the sections of code I was working on when fixing specific bugs.

Unfortunately, sorting by Creation Time doesn't seem to work since some dates are showing up out of order.

And sorting by ID was OK for a while, but when we moved to a different revision control system I had to try copying my marker files to the projects in the new source tree and eclipse's notion of current bookmark ID changed so all the new bookmarks appear out of sequence with the old ones.

So it looks like I'm back to trying to deal with sorting by Creation Time.

One other data point; if I ctl-a and copy all of the bookmarks into a text file, the date shows up as a long int value; sorting on this value seems to produce the correct result.

So I'm not sure why eclipse fails to sort properly.

Comment: I really wish Eclipse addressed this, it's still there with Neon.2 . In addition to the use you mentioned, another thing is that when I have a lot of bookmarks I could really, really use the possibility to sort them with the newest on top, and it's sad that Eclipse does have this functionality but it doesn't seem to work. As of now I cannot even make sense of how that sorting works at all; [this](http://farm1.staticflickr.com/570/31850757510_01c2a48c9d_b.jpg) is an example of the puzzle, "sorted" in descending order; what are those dates sorted on ? Not alphabetical,not year, not time, what ?